# Symfony2, expression validator is not working

Tags: validation, symfony

The expression validator is not working.
I am following Symfony2 documentation example:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/constraints/Expression.html

In my simplified case,
C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj3_27\app\config\validation.yml

```
    MeetingBundle]Entity\SearchLtk:
        constraints:
            - Expression:
                expression: "this.keywL<2"
                message: "Input more search words"
```

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj3_27\app\config\config.yml

```
framework:
    validation:    { enabled: true, enable_annotations: true }
```

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\proj3_27\src\MeetingBundle\Entity\SearchLtk.php

```
    /**
     * SearchLtk
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="search_ltk",indexes={@ORM\Index(columns={"zip"}, flags={"fulltext"})})
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MeetingBundle\Repository\SearchLocRepository" )
     */
    class SearchLtk
    {....

         /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="keyw", type="string", nullable = true)
         */
        private $keyw;    

   ... 
        /**
         *
         * @return integer
         */
            public function keywL($keyw)
        {
            $kArr = preg_split( "/[;,\.]+/", $keyw ); 
            foreach ( $kArr as $key=>$item ) {
                $item=trim($item); 
    // the string becomes "", but length is 1, count returns 1
    //but empty returns correctly 
                if( count($item) == 0 or (empty($item))){
                    unset($kArr[$key]);
                }
            }
            return count($kArr );
        } 
...
```

Comment: What is currrently happening and what are you expecting?

Comment: If you want the expression to execute the `keywL` public function might have to use parentheses.  Meaning `"this.keywL() < 2"` instead of `"this.keywL<2"`, then inside keywL function, refer to the value using $this->keyw.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should not have methods in Entity.

2) Checkout this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php